# Buttons that doesn't show well: Leaflet Routing machine

Tags: leaflet, open-source-routing-machine

I have a basic Leaflet map (v1.7)

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
<script>
    // base map
        const map = L.map('map').setView([48.505, 2.09], 11);
    
        const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

to which I'm a adding the JS and CSS files of the geocoder to find addresses (1.5.5, [here](https://www.cdnpkg.com/perliedman-leaflet-control-geocoder/1.5.5))

the Leaflet routing machine, modified for Openroute service, where I've just added some buttons  [linked here in javascript](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-routing-machine-scasb.js) , with a modified CSS for the buttons [here](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-routing-machine.css)
originated from [this info page](https://framagit.org/gegeweb/scasb-calcul-itineraires-velo)

and the code:

```
// first variables

var apikey = 'COPY_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
let routingprofile = 'driving-car';

        const osrRouter = L.routing.openroute(apikey, {
    format: 'json',
    language: 'fr',
    "timeout": 30 * 1000, // 30"
    "retries": 2,
    "retryDelay": 1000,
    "retryOn": [],
    "profile": routingprofile,
    routingQueryParams: {
        "attributes": [
            "avgspeed",
            "percentage"
        ],
        "elevation": "true",
        "extra_info": [
            "waytype",
            "surface",
            "waycategory",
            "suitability",
            "steepness",
            "tollways",
            "traildifficulty",
            "osmid",
            "roadaccessrestrictions",
            "countryinfo"
        ],
        "id": "rounting_request",
        "instructions": "true",
        "instructions_format": "text",
        "language": "fr",
        "maneuvers": "true",
        "geometry": "true",
        "roundabout_exits": "true",
        "preference": "recommended"
    }
});

var control = L.Routing.control({

    router: osrRouter,
    position: 'topright',
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    reverseWaypoints: true,
addWaypoints: true,
drivingcar: true,
drivinghgv: true,
cyclingregular: true,
cyclingroad: true,
cyclingmountain: true,
cyclingelectric: true,
footwalking: true,
foothiking: true,
wheelchair: true,
   geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({}) 

});

control.addTo(map);
```

The routing works fine, but the icons are not showing properly:

[image]

If you close the small window, buttons won't be hidden and will be messy:

[image]

The problem doesn't occur on [this page](https://ptv-logistics.github.io/fl-labs/), that's using an untouched original version of Leaflet routing machine without openrouteservice ([link to javascript](https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@3.2.12/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js)) ([introduction](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine)):

[image]

where buttons disappear when you close the window, as you would expect:

[image]

I need to either fix the glitch or make those buttons hide on closing the small control window.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you modified plugin and now it doesn't work as you would expect it?

Comment: @TomazicM Hello TomazicM, no even before I modified it (adding some other buttons just after this.options.addWaypoints and this.options.reverseWaypoints), those two button had this behaviour: not hiding when clicking the close button and having a different style than a normal Leaflet routing machine engine ; so I'm just signaling my file is modified but that modification isn't the cause for the error